# Частично одинаковые запросы в БД Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php8

В приложении есть деление по пользователям. И есть множество крудов, которые должны возвращать данные пользователя. В таблицах есть поле owner_id. Вопрос заключается в том, как можно сделать какой-либо конструктор запроса, чтобы каждый запрос улетал с where('owner_id', $ownerId)? Этот запрос должен улетать с разных моделей
Вот несколько примеров:

В TaskRepository есть запрос на получение списка задач:

```
public function withChildren()
{
    return Task::whereNull('parent_id')
        ->with('tags')
        ->ownerId($this->userId)
        ->paginate(5);
}
```

Также есть шаблон фильтрации:

```
public function filter(array $data)
{
    $filter = app()->make(TaskFilter::class, ['queryParams' => array_filter($data)]);

    $tasks = Task::filter($filter)->get();

    return $tasks;
}
```

Вот пример запроса в TaskFilter:

```
public function priorityId($value)
{
    $this->builder->where('priority_id', $value);
}
```

Такая же ситуация обстоит в модели Category, Tags и т.д.
Ко всем запросам нужно добавлять **where('owner_id', $ownerId);**

Подскажите, как это грамотно сделать

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант использовать трейт с локальным скоупом для фильтрации запроса по owner_id в Laravel. Трейт предоставит удобный метод для применения скоупа внутри модели. Вот пример:

```php
trait OwnerScopeTrait
{
    public function scopeByOwner($query, $ownerId)
    {
        return $query->where('owner_id', $ownerId);
    }
}
```

И затем ты можешь использовать этот трейт в своих моделях:

```php
class Tag extends Model
{
    use OwnerScopeTrait;

}
```

Теперь, когда ты хочешь получить записи с определенным owner_id, ты можешь использовать локальный скоуп в своих запросах:

```php
$specificOwnerRecords = YourModel::byOwner(2)->get();
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, если метод используется одной моделью, то трейт можно не создавать? Или же можно сейчас вынести этот метод в трейд "на всякий случай", если в дальнейшем приложение расширится и метод понадобится где еще?

Comment: По хорошему если используется в одном месте, то не нужно, лучше оставить метод в самой модели